# $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$ is noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noetherian

How can we prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$ is noetherian except by using Hilbert basis theorem?

How can we find a sequence of ideals that satisfy the ACC?

Comment: You have to prove that EVERY chain of ideals stabilises, not just one.

Comment: One approach would be to show that the map $I\mapsto I\cap \mathbb{Z}$ from ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$ to ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ is finite-to-one.

Comment: How can we do that? Is there a general formula for the ideals of that ring? @SoumyaSinha

Comment: You don't need the Hilbert basis theorem, necessarily. It's a free $\mathbb Z$-module of rank $2$.

Comment: For a more natural proof see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705806/mathbb-z-sqrt-5-is-noetherian?rq=1). It works for all $\mathbb{Z}[d]$.